# Turn On/Off or Enable/Disable variables efficiently

Tags: python

I am working on some optimization problem and I have a set of equations with slack variables for some input variables representing constraints. Depending on the input data, I may or may not need all the slack variables. It will be a hassle to re-write the equations each time to include/exclude such variables. Therefore, I am planning to keep all the slack variables in place and am looking for suggestions to quickly turn these variables on or off based on problem requirements. Assuming that the following is representative of the set of equations:

`X1 + slack1 = y1
X2 + slack2 = y2
X3 + slack3 = y3
.
.
.`.

How can I turn a few or all of the slack variables to 0 (essentially disabling them) in shortest possible way? I should point out that the variables will be used in multiple places within the code.

One approach I was thinking of, was to create a dictionary of slack variables at the beginning of the code - such as `slack= {'slack1':0,'slack2':1,'slack3':}` and then refer to those variables as `slack['slack1']` throughout the code.

Any other, more efficient Pythonic suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply use `tuples`:

```
slacks = [("slack1", 1), ("slack2", 0), ("slack3", 1)]
for a,b in slacks:
    if b==0:
        #do whatever
    else:
        #do whatever
```

Accessing elements directly will be easier too. To access `bool` field of slack3, we can just use `slacks[2][1]`

If not list you can simply use `slack` variables as `tuples`:

```
slack1 = tuple('slack1', 1)
slack1[0] #acess value
slack1[1] #access on/off
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can turn your equations into functions, then just pass those slack variables as optional keyword parameters

```
def func1(x, y, slack=0):
    ... # your code

    return result
```

Whenever those vars are irrelevant you just omit them in the client code.
Because you will not change your code based in requested input for the problem. What channges is the input provided and injected in the functions.

Otherwise to disable it manually you could just group them in any structure you like and reset them all to 0. But I think that's not the right thing to do.